# R plotly line color by value range

Tags: colors, r-plotly, timeserieschart

I would like to make this kind of graph (here from [Our World In data](https://ourworldindata.org/explorers/coronavirus-data-explorer?zoomToSelection=true&time=2021-01-26..2021-08-13&facet=none&pickerSort=desc&pickerMetric=new_cases_per_million&Metric=Confirmed%20cases&Interval=7-day%20rolling%20average&Relative%20to%20Population=true&Color%20by%20test%20positivity=true&country=%7EKHM) ) where the line color varies by value range.

edit : adding a screenshot to make it clearer :

[image]

With plotly, I found this [example](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/448200_6bb02977b4c04e0da508ac0131f71d48.html) but working with type = scatter and mode = markers plot and not with lines:

```
    x <- seq(from = -2,
         to = 2,
         b = 0.1)
y <- sin(x)

p11 <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(type = "scatter",
            x = ~x,
            y = ~y,
            mode = "markers",
            marker = list(size = 10,
                          color = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(10,"Spectral"))(41))) %>% 
  layout(title = "Multicolored sine curve",
         xaxis = list(title = "x-axis"),
         yaxis = list(title = "y-axis"))
p11
```

is there any ways to use the colorRampPalette or values range but with line (actually it's a time series)

```
    x <- seq(from = -2,
         to = 2,
         b = 0.1)
y <- sin(x)

p11 <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(type = "scatter",
            x = ~x,
            y = ~y,
            mode = "lines",
            line = list(width = 1,
                          color = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(10,"Spectral"))(41))) %>% 
  layout(title = "Multicolored sine curve",
         xaxis = list(title = "x-axis"),
         yaxis = list(title = "y-axis"))
p11
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can, but the more points you have the better it will look. Note that I change the .1 in `x`, to .001.

```
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)

x <- seq(from = -2,
         to = 2,
         b = 0.001)
y <- sin(x)

z = cut(x, breaks = 5, include.lowest = T)

p11 <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_lines(x = ~x,
            y = ~y,
            color = ~z,
            colors = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(10,"Spectral"))(length(x))) %>% 
  layout(title = "Multicolored sine curve",
         xaxis = list(title = "x-axis"),
         yaxis = list(title = "y-axis"))
p11
```

[image]

If I change that .001 back to .1, it's a bit ugly! You can see the gaps.

[image]